# How to represent a workflow chain using networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Page1  Page2  Page3  Page4
 A     B      C      D
```

Is there a way to show a simple directed flow between the pages?

Comment: what information do you have to base the flow on? there are no links shown in the data here so it would be a lonely-looking graph.

Comment: Yes.. I just need to show a graph starting from A to D in that sequence itself. I mean the graph should be like A--B--C--D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your dataframe is something like this,

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame(['A','B','C','D'], columns=['page'])
print(df.T)
>>>       0  1  2  3
>>> page  A  B  C  D
```

then you need to iterate over the pages in sequence. networkx has a helper function, `utils.pairwise` that you can use - though of course other ways exist to iterate over a list and get elements (i, i+1):

```
from networkx import utils

G = nx.DiGraph() # need a directed graph
G.add_edges_from(utils.pairwise(df.page))
print(G.edges())
>>> [('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C')]

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True) # quick/low-effort visualization
```

[image: graph rendering like this]